# simple loop two pixelsearch won't work is there something wrong?

Tags: autoit

Hi I'm newbie using autoit so please guys be gentle :)
so i make a flash internet browser script it perfectly works on single pixelsearch loop, however it won't work if a put another two different pixelsearch is there something wrong? :(

```
HotKeySet("{HOME}", "Start")
HotKeySet("{END}", "_Exit")

While 1
    Sleep(200)
WEnd

Func Start()
    While 1

        $colorgreen = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0x00FF00)
        If Not @error Then
            MouseClick("Left", $colorgreen[0], $colorgreen[1], 1, 1) ;spam left click on the green-color areas
            Sleep(100)

        Else
            PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0xFF0063)
            If Not @error Then
                SoundPlay(@WindowsDir & "\media\tada.wav", 1) ;Alert me using very loud noise when it founds pink color lol
                Sleep(100)
            Else
                Send("{F5}") ;Refresh button
            EndIf
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Start

Func _Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_Exit
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? Currently the logic is: If there is a green pixel then click it, otherwise if there is a redish pixel then play a sound, and if there is neither then refresh.

Comment: it wont really work at all,,, i think there's something wrong in my else or misplace elseif endif :(

Comment: Well the first step is always to tidy the code (Ctrl+T in SciTE), that indents the code correctly so you can read the If statements easily. I've done that and edited the post. Next step is to add `ConsoleWrite` trace statements to see where the code is getting to.

Comment: you might need to add a check for different shades using the 6th param called shade-variation. As the default is a perfect match (0 shades).

Comment: You cant guess the color code, you need to get the exact code.
Also, as they suggested, you can play with variations, but that not as reliable as the first solution.
Do a printscreen, paste it at paint and save it as .BMP . Then use photoshop or any other software that can tell you the color code.

Comment: if the issue is with color you can actually use autoit to get the hex color of an area below your mouse.  https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm